# Eclipse Juno 64 bit Crash on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

i try to run eclipse juno 64 bit on ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, but i got following errors:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fddfa424c11, pid=5850, tid=140591821719296
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0+0x1cdc11]  gtk_text_buffer_get_tag_table+0x61
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/iwan/dev/eclipse-juno/hs_err_pid5850.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it could be related to a bug in GTK+2.0. Try upgrading if possible. There's a thread here about the bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/391398